# Numbers $m$ for which coefficients of the polynomial $p(m,x)$ are relatively prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

From [A248667](https://oeis.org/A248667):

> The polynomial $p(n,x)$ is defined as the numerator when the sum
> $$1 + \frac{1}{nx + 1} + \frac{1}{(nx + 1)(nx + 2)} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(nx + 1)(nx + 2)\cdots(nx + n - 1)}$$
> is written as a fraction with denominator
> $$(nx + 1)(nx + 2)\cdots(nx + n - 1)$$

The first six polynomials:

$$p(1,x) = 1$$
$$p(2,x) = 2 (1 + x)$$
$$p(3,x) = 5 + 12 x + 9x^2$$
$$p(4,x) = 4 (4 + 17 x + 28 x^2 + 16 x^3)$$
$$p(5,x) = 5 (13 + 84 x + 225 x^2 + 275 x^3 + 125 x^4)$$
$$p(6,x) = 2 (163 + 1455 x + 5562 x^2 + 10800 x^3 + 10368 x^4 + 3888 x^5)$$
Let $a(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $m$ for which coefficients of the polynomial $p(m,x)$ are relatively prime.

For example:
$$p(3,x) = 5 + 12 x + 9x^2$$
$$\operatorname{gcd}(5,12,9)=1$$

The sequence begins:
$$1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29, 31, 33, 41, 43, 47, 49, 51, 53, 57$$

Let $b(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $m$ for which
$$\sum |\mu(p_j+1)|=0$$

Here
$$m=\prod p_j^{k_j}$$
where $p_j$ are distinct prime divisors of $m$ and $k_j$ are their powers. Obviously $\mu(n)$ is the Moebius function.

The sequence begins
$$3, 7, 9, 11, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 31, 33, 43, 47, 49, 51, 53, 57, 59, 63, 67$$

I conjecture that $b(n)$ is subsequence of $a(n)$.

Up to $a(60)=167$ there are only $12$ terms which are not belong to $b(n)$:
$$1, 29, 41, 61, 73, 87, 101, 109, 113, 123, 137, 157$$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The polynomials are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A248664 and the sequence $a(n)$ at https://oeis.org/A248667

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterexample: $463 \in b(n)$ (it's a prime and $464 = 2^4 \cdot 29$ is not squarefree), but $463 \not \in a(n)$ because it's a factor of the GCD of the coefficients of $p(463, x)$.

Comment: The latter is equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^{462} 1/k!$ being divisible by 463, is there any way to see this without computations?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, I computed it. The sequence of primes in $a(n)$ doesn't appear to be in OEIS.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for answer! Can you compute another counterexamples? At least 2 more to add the sequence to the OEIS. By the way, the numbers might be called your last name.

Comment: @Notamathematician, the counterexamples up to 10000 are 463, 1389, 3241, 4167, 5093, 7871, 8797, 9723, but absent a reason for expecting there to be a relationship between $a$ and $b$ I don't really think that the sequence is motivated enough to justify its inclusion in OEIS.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you very much! All these numbers are divisible by 463 and the result of division is $b(n)$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, also, about your draft edit to A248667: maybe A000522(n-1) instead of A000522(n+1)? There also exists A248666, where you can put the same comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, see also A064384.